# (User was removed) reputation reduction when I have never posted any questions or answers

Tags: discussion, bug

I have never posted any questions or answers on this site (except comments). All my reputation points here is from the 100 bonus for joining and from approved edits

Yet today I have got a notification for (-2 -2) reputation, total reduction of 4, with the reason being (User was removed)

Since I have never posted any questions or answers I am not sure what part of my reputation was from voting, which was supposedly removed

How does the (User was removed) reputation adjustment work?

Comment: you probably lost rep acquired of two approved suggested edits (when edited posts were removed, following the removal of some user)

Comment: @gnat is probably on the money here. If you check your [reputation history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/8057/user13267?tab=reputation&sort=time) you can see that you do have a number of +2s in addition to the standard association bonus. Two of those were presumably lost when the user was removed.

Comment: @Lilienthal did that remove their post as well?

Comment: @user13267 naturally, thus why you got the -2... in other news, I've been getting several "user has been removed" lately...

Comment: @user13267 There is a [distinction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88996/260382) between user deletion and destruction. The latter is rare for established users and will remove all of a users posts. The former is more common and IIRC will only remove negatively scored posts. (There is no way of determining which posts or which user was involved when you spot those deletions.)